# Binding multiple tableviews to multiple NSArrayContollers results in crash

Tags: swift, xcode, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I have two `NSTableviews` the first one is bound to the first `NSArraycontroller` and arranged objects checked as as well as the selectionIndexes and works just fine.

I have a second table view and when I bind it to the second `NSArrayController` it crashes with

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

I am using Xcode 9.4.1. Has anyone experienced the problem??

Comment: Add the exception breakpoint and get the exception reason which is most likely *This class is not key-value compliant for the key xyz*. Then debug your design.

Comment: I finally got it to work, Seems there was something wrong with the tableview. I deleted it and created a new one a viola works just. fine.